# How to automatically remove dead Kubernetes nodes from cluster in bare metal deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking for a tool that will remove dead (NotReady) nodes from my bare metal Kubernetes cluster after a timeout. It needs to make sure it is on the etcd majority side of any network partition before removing any nodes.

The problem we have with dead nodes is that pods get stuck in 'Terminating', holding onto persistent volume claims with ReadWriteOnce, until the node is removed from the cluster. This prevents them from starting up elsewhere.

Does such a tool/script exist or is there another way to achieve the same result? Tx.